# Tab Character Entity for XHTML?

Tags: xhtml, character-entities

Does anyone know what the character entity for a tab is in xhtml?
(Um if there is one)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(X)HTML has no special support for tabs: they're just another whitespace character, regardless of whether you escape them or not.

Comment: Indeed. There are, however, some cases where a raw tab in an attribute value will be parsed away to nothing, whereas a &#9; character reference will survive into attribute.nodeValue.

Comment: They can be used in `<textarea>` tags, for spacing.

Comment: And for in `pre` tags.

Answer (score 7):

Try `&#9;`. The TAB is ASCII character #9.

But it may not show up as you'd expect, anyway, since HTML ignores whitespace in most instances.

Answer (score -1):

What most people do to simulate tabs is use DD & DT tags.  They are intended creating a glossary:

```
term
    definition goes here

term
    definition goes here
```